# TVML resumable player (in tvOS 14)

Tags: tvos, tvml, tvjs

I have a TVML/TVJS app that presents a document with a number of playable items. Each item is a lockup element with an event handler to launch the built-in media player, very much like in the example project:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/tvmljs/playing_media_in_a_client-server_app

In the example code, the event handler creates a new `Player` object from scratch every time it is triggered, but I would like the player to be resumable: when the user exits the player (e.g. with the menu button) and returns by selecting the item again, I would like to resume the player where it left off.

Before, I would do this by creating `Player` objects for each item already when the document is loaded (including `Playlist` and `MediaItem`), and just execute `player.select()` or `player.play()` in the event handler. That would work well.

Since tvOS 14, creating all these `Player` objects when the document loads seems to overload the app (perhaps it already starts fetching all these items from the network). So I no longer create the `Player` objects beforehand, but I check in the event handler if I already have a `Player` for the item, and I create it when it's the first time, otherwise I reuse the `Player` object.

But even though I checked that I reuse the existing `Player` object, calling `play()` or `present()` causes the playback to restart from the beginning. So what would be the appropriate way to obtain a resumable player?

Comment: Did you try setting a `resumeTime` on your player item?

Comment: @anders Not yet, but that seems the suggestion here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/26083 It seems you have to record the position using constant events: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/18620